# How can I use bitset in map?

Tags: c++, bitset

I am trying to store 0 to 25 numbers along with its 5 bit representation using bitset.
Here is the code :

```
int main()
{
   
   map<int, bitset<5> > myMap;
   myMap[0] = 00000;
   myMap[1] = 00001;
   myMap[2] = 00010;
   myMap[3] = 00011;

   // Like this I have stored 0 to 25 numbers.     
    
   auto pos = myMap.find(2);
   cout<< pos-> second <<endl;  // output is 01000
   
   pos = myMap.find(3);
   cout<< pos->second <<endl;   // output is 01001

   pos = myMap.find(15);
   cout<< pos->second <<endl;   // output is 01001

   pos = myMap.find(12);
   cout<< pos->second <<endl;   // output is 00000
   return 0;
}
```

It seems that my output is wrong.
Where I am wrong ?

Comment: `0xxx` is octal number. You might want `0b0010`

Comment: binary literals are available since C++14 and they look like: `0b00011`.  Your `00011` is octal representation of value. Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal vote to close as typo.

Comment: `myMap[2] =2;` will work as well.

Comment: Anyway why do you need this map? Conversion `int` <--> `std::bitset` cost literally nothing.

Comment: @ Marek R :  Actually I am trying to use the Succinct Trie data structure. Where I want to create bit vector on which I want to apply rank and select. So if your Trie node has 2 children then in bit vector I am going to store 00010. If node has 5 children then 00101 etc.

Comment: If you know anything about LOUDS ( Level-Order Unary Degree Sequence) please let me know. I am trying to implement it in a silly way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
myMap[2] = 00010;
```

The `int` literal is converted to a `bitset`. The octal literal `00010` is decimal 8, which prints the output `01000`. Similarly, the literal `00011` is decimal 9, which prints `01001`.

You seem to want:

```
myMap[0] = 0;
myMap[1] = 1;
myMap[2] = 2;
myMap[3] = 3;
// etc.

// or simply
for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
  myMap[i] = i;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/448KxP).

Answer (score 2):

`0xxx` is an octal number (base 8). You might want `0b0010` (C++14) or `"00010"`.